# Flex Box Items not aligning with the above row

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I am trying to build a small grid-like component. This component would have a header of columns and then data rows. Obviously, all the data would be passed to this component using props. I am facing a small CSS issue. I want the text of the row to align with the header text. See the red arrows that I made, I want the "Plan" text to go directly under "type" test. Similarly, the "April" text should go directly under the "last modified" text. Here's a html/css example of my component structure.[image]

I know I am using two different flex boxes for this and what I need isn't the default behaviour but how do I achieve it? Here's my CSS

```
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
}
.header {
  background: grey;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  
  /* border: 1px solid yellow; */
}
.column {
  flex-direction: column;
}
.justify-content {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.items {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
.basis {
  flex-basis: 0px;
}
```

Comment: You could also do `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);` but honestly this looks like a job for a `<table>`.

Answer (score 0):

You could set explicit `max-width` values, or more straightforward would be to use `display: grid`, but if you’re displaying tabular data then this would be an appropriate use case for a native `<table>` structure.

Comment: And obviously you get the functionality you’re after for free in a table because that’s what it’s designed for.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of using `CSS` [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
}
.header {
  background: grey;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
}

.header div {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.items {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr)
}

.items > div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <div>Name</div>
      <div>Type</div>
      <div>Last Modified</div>
    </div>
    <div class="items">
      <div>Account</div>
      <div>Plan</div>
      <div>April</div>
    </div>
  <div>
```